# Merge rows with the same id while retrieving the max values from certain column

Tags: python

I am trying to merge multiple rows and retrieve the max value from the columns:
say I have the following data frame:

```
id  Reaction1 Reaction2 Reaction3 
A      4         3         2       
A      1         2         1      
A      5         1         0       
B      3         2         1       
B      1         1         2
```

and I would like to merge the row to show the max value from each column:

```
id Reaction1 Reaction2 Reaction3 
A     5          3         2      
B     3          2         2
```

The other question is:

keep other rows (don't group them) and override the column using the max(abs), the reason is that I might have other columns information I would like to keep:

```
id  Reaction1 Reaction2 Reaction3 Other_col
A      5         3         2       x
A      5         3         2       y
A      5         3         2       z
B      3         2         2       x
B      3         2         2       y
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can just do max of the groupby object:

```
df.groupby('id').max()
```

outputs:

```
    Rx1  Rx2  Rx3
id
A     5    3    2
B     3    2    2
```

If you want 'id' to stay a column instead of the index you can just change it to:

```
df.groupby('id').max().reset_index()
```